# How do I insert scrollbars inside a new window with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a program that calculates how to get 24 using 4 numbers:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<title>Calculate 24 Solutions</title>
<script src="clock.js"></script>
The game 24 (aka. Combine 4) gives you 4 numbers, and you have to do operations using all four numbers to make 24. Some of the questions are quite tricky! If you need help getting the solution, click the button below and follow the directions! It will give you a list of all the solutions. One operation you may not be familliar with is modulo. It takes 2 numbers, divides to first number by the second number, and returns the remainder.<br><br>
+ is addition<br>
- is subtraction<br>
* is multiplication<br>
/ is division<br>
^ is exponents<br>
% is modulo<br><br>
<script>
var solutions = []; var power; var mod; var powStr; var modStr; var answerStr;
function doop(var1, var2, op) {
    if (op == '+') {
        return Number(var1) + Number(var2);
    } else if (op == '-') {
        return Number(var1) - Number(var2);
    } else if (op == '*') {
        return Number(var1) * Number(var2);
    } else if (op == '/') {
        return Number(var1) / Number(var2);
    } else if (op == '%') {
        return Number(var1) % Number(var2);
    } else if (op == '^') {
        return Math.pow(Number(var1), Number(var2));
    } else {
        alert("Invalid number or operation! Cannot doop() these parameters!");
    }
}
function getNumbers() {
    solutions = [];
    var invalid = false;
    alert("Let's start calculating!");
    power = prompt("Include exponents (the power operation)?");
    mod = prompt("Include the modulo operation?");
    if (power.toLowerCase().substring(0, 1) == "y") {
        power = "yes";
    } else if (power.toLowerCase().substring(0, 1) == "n") {
        power = "no";
    } if (mod.toLowerCase().substring(0, 1) == "y") {
        mod = "yes";
    } else if (mod.toLowerCase().substring(0, 1) == "n") {
        mod = "no";
    }
    var a = prompt("What is number 1?");
    var b = prompt("What is number 2?");
    var c = prompt("What is number 3?");
    var d = prompt("What is number 4?");
    if (isNaN(a) || a > 13 || a < 0 || a == '' || a === null) {
        alert("The first number is invalid!");
        invalid = true;
    }
    if (isNaN(b) || b > 13 || b < 0 || b == '' || b === null) {
        alert("The second number is invalid!");
        invalid = true;
    }
    if (isNaN(c) || c > 13 || c < 0 || c == '' || c === null) {
        alert("The third number is invalid!");
        invalid = true;
    }
    if (isNaN(d) || d > 13 || d < 0 || d == '' || d === null) {
        alert("The fourth number is invalid!");
        invalid = true;
    }
    if (power.toLowerCase() != "yes" && power.toLowerCase() != "no") {
        alert("The exponent prompt response is invalid!");
        invalid = true;
    }
    if (mod.toLowerCase() != "yes" && mod.toLowerCase() != "no") {
        alert("The modulo prompt response is invalid!");
        invalid = true;
    }
    while (invalid === true) {
        power = prompt("Include exponents (the power operation)?");
        mod = prompt("Include the modulo operation?");
        a = prompt("What is number 1?");
        b = prompt("What is number 2?");
        c = prompt("What is number 3?");
        d = prompt("What is number 4?");
        invalid = false;
        if (isNaN(a) || a > 13 || a < 0 || a == '' || a === null) {
            alert("The first number is invalid!");
            invalid = true;
        }
        if (isNaN(b) || b > 13 || b < 0 || b == '' || b === null) {
            alert("The second number is invalid!");
            invalid = true;
        }
        if (isNaN(c) || c > 13 || c < 0 || c == '' || c === null) {
            alert("The third number is invalid!");
            invalid = true;
        }
        if (isNaN(d) || d > 13 || d < 0 || d == '' || d === null) {
            alert("The fourth number is invalid!");
            invalid = true;
        }
        if (power.toLowerCase() != "yes" && power.toLowerCase() != "no") {
            alert("The exponent prompt response is invalid!");
            invalid = true;
        }
        if (mod.toLowerCase() != "yes" && mod.toLowerCase() != "no") {
            alert("The modulo prompt response is invalid!");
            invalid = true;
        }
        if (power.toLowerCase().substring(0, 1) == "y") {
            power = "yes";
        } else if (power.toLowerCase().substring(0, 1) == "n") {
            power = "no";
        } if (mod.toLowerCase().substring(0, 1) == "y") {
            mod = "yes";
        } else if (mod.toLowerCase().substring(0, 1) == "n") {
            mod = "no";
        }
    }
    return [a, b, c, d];
}
function calculate(a, b, c, d) {
    var op1 = ['+', '-', '*', '/'];
    var op2 = ['+', '-', '*', '/'];
    var op3 = ['+', '-', '*', '/'];
    if (mod.toLowerCase() == "yes") {
        op1.push('%');
        op2.push('%');
        op3.push('%');
    }
    if (power.toLowerCase() == "yes") {
        op1.push('^');
        op2.push('^');
        op3.push('^');
    }
    var i1; var i2; var i3;
    for (i1 = 0; i1 < op1.length; i1++) {
        for (i2 = 0; i2 < op2.length; i2++) {
            for (i3 = 0; i3 < op3.length; i3++) {
                if (doop(doop(doop(a, b, op1[i1]), c, op2[i2]), d, op3[i3]) == 24) {
                    solutions.push('((' + a + op1[i1] + b + ')' + op2[i2] + c + ')' + op3[i3] + d + ' = 24');
                }
                if (doop(doop(a, doop(b, c, op1[i1]), op2[i2]), d, op3[i3]) == 24) {
                    solutions.push('(' + a + op2[i2] + '(' + b + op1[i1] + c + '))' + op3[i3] + d + ' = 24');
                }
                if (doop(doop(a, b, op1[i1]), doop(c, d, op2[i2]), op3[i3]) == 24) {
                    solutions.push('(' + a + op1[i1] + b + ')' + op3[i3] + '(' + c + op2[i2] + d + ') = 24');
                }
                if (doop(a, doop(doop(b, c, op1[i1]), d, op2[i2]), op3[i3]) == 24) {
                    solutions.push(a + op3[i3] + '((' + b + op1[i1] + c + ')' + op2[i2] + d + ') = 24');
                }
                if (doop(a, doop(b, doop(c, d, op1[i1]), op2[i2]), op3[i3]) == 24) {
                    solutions.push(a + op3[i3] + '(' + b + op2[i2] + '(' + c + op1[i1] + d + ')) = 24');
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
function enumerate() {
    var num = getNumbers();
    var a; var b; var c; var d;
    for (var ai = 0; ai < 4; ai++) {
        a = num[ai];
        for (var bi = 0; bi < 4; bi++) {
            if (bi != ai) {
                b = num[bi];
                for (var ci = 0; ci < 4; ci++) {
                    if (ci != ai && ci != bi) {
                        c = num[ci];
                        for (var di = 0; di < 4; di++) {
                            if (di != ai && di != bi && di != ci) {
                                d = num[di];
                                calculate(a, b, c, d);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if (power.toLowerCase() == "yes") {
        powStr = "did";
    } else {
        powStr = "did not";
    }
    if (mod.toLowerCase() == "yes") {
        modStr = "did";
    } else {
        modStr = "did not";
    }
    if (solutions.length == 0) {
        answerStr = "Sorry, no solution found.";
    } else {
        answerStr = solutions.length + " solutions found:";
    } 
    var solutionWindow = window.open('','_blank','width=500,height=1000');
    solutionWindow.document.write("<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"style.css\">Your numbers are:<br>\n" + num[0] + ', ' + num[1] + ', ' + num[2] + ', and ' + num[3] + "<br><br>\n" + 'You ' + powStr + ' include exponents.<br>You ' + modStr + ' include modulo.' + '<br><br>\n' + answerStr + '<br>\n');
    solutionWindow.document.write(solutions.join("<br>\n"));
    solutionWindow.document.write("<br><br>\n<a href=\"#\"><button>Back to top</button></a><br>");
    solutionWindow.document.write("<br>\n<button onclick=\"javascript: self.close()\">Close Window</button>");
    solutionWindow.focus();
}
</script>
<button onclick="javascript: enumerate()">Calculate Solution</button>
```

My style.css:

```
html {
  background-color: lightYellow;
  overflow: scroll;
}
button {
  height: 50px;
  width: 150px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 25px;
  color: white;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(white, lightGreen, green, darkGreen, green, lightGreen, white);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(white, lightGreen, green, darkGreen, green, lightGreen, white);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(white, lightGreen, green, darkGreen, green, lightGreen, white);
  background-image: linear-gradient(white, lightGreen, green, darkGreen, green, lightGreen, white);
}
button:focus {
  color: black;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(darkGreen, green, lightGreen, white, lightGreen, green, darkGreen);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(darkGreen, green, lightGreen, white, lightGreen, green, darkGreen);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(darkGreen, green, lightGreen, white, lightGreen, green, darkGreen);
  background-image: linear-gradient(darkGreen, green, lightGreen, white, lightGreen, green, darkGreen);
}
button:hover {
  color: white;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(white, lightBlue, blue, darkBlue, blue, lightBlue, white);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(white, lightBlue, blue, darkBlue, blue, lightBlue, white);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(white, lightBlue, blue, darkBlue, blue, lightBlue, white);
  background-image: linear-gradient(white, lightBlue, blue, darkBlue, blue, lightBlue, white);
}
button:active {
  color: black;
  border: none;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(darkBlue, blue, lightBlue, white, lightBlue, blue, darkBlue);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(darkBlue, blue, lightBlue, white, lightBlue, blue, darkBlue);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(darkBlue, blue, lightBlue, white, lightBlue, blue, darkBlue);
  background-image: linear-gradient(darkBlue, blue, lightBlue, white, lightBlue, blue, darkBlue);
}
```

However, in IE when it opens the new window, there are no scrollbars so I can't see all of the solutions sometimes. It works fine in Google Chrome, though.

Comment: That's quite a lot of code. Could you create a [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: I have apache on my computer

Comment: I used IE 9 and it doesn't work

Comment: I can't make a jsFiddle because document.write is diabled and plus, alert doesn't work either

Comment: Do you want a CSS Solution?

Comment: Sure! I just want scrollbars in the new window.

Comment: See, heres the JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/y4xfA/1/

It doesn't work

Comment: Yes I have, but it still doesn't work...?

Comment: Here are my drive.google.com editey files: https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0ByRQa2x0YzESWmhjelFFRkJUbzA&usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
var solutionWindow = window.open('','_blank','scrollbars=1,width=500,height=1000');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `javascript`, You can follow [plalx's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19911778/2151050)

Otherwise if you want to use CSS:

```
html,body {
    overflow:scroll; // I'm not sure whether your results always need a scroll-bar to see it, if yes use `auto` 
}
```

to inject this css into your popup window:

```
solutionWindow.document.write("<style>html,body { overflow:scroll; }</style>);
```

or just add it to your `style.css` file

Comment: I did add it in my style.css.!?

Comment: Did you try (debug) it!?

Comment: I added the "body" part, and it ***has*** scrollbars now, but it doesn't scroll to the bottom of the page! It just scrolls half a millimeter and stops.

Comment: Correction: half a centimeter